# How to reload the table on clicking the submit and save changes button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, crud

I want to know if it is possible to reload the table when i click the save changes or the submit button instead of just trying to refresh the page. I cant seem to get how to refresh it. is it maybe because of the table being rendered on page load and isnt given a function name?

This is the html along with the script:

```cshtml
@model mvcpractive1.Models.PersonDb

@{
    Layout = null;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>GetDetails</title>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div style=" width:550px; padding:40px; margin-top:5%; margin-bottom:5%; border:1px solid black;" class="container center-div">

    <form>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PersonName">Person Id</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PersonId" name="PersonId" placeholder="Id" disabled>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PersonName">Person Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PersonName" name="PersonName" placeholder="Name">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="PersonName">Person Age</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PersonAge" name="PersonAge" placeholder="Age">
      </div>

      <button id="snddet" style="position: absolute; margin-top:40px; margin-left: 190px" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

      <select style="margin-top:10px" class="mdb-select md-form" id="PersonCountry" name="PersonCountry">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your Country</option>
        @foreach (var item in (List<String>)ViewBag.list) 
        {
          <option value='@item'>@item</option>
        }
      </select>

      <select class="mdb-select md-form" id="PersonCity" name="PersonCity" style=" display: none">
      </select>

    </form>

    <button id="show" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-left:20px" class="btn btn-primary">Get Table</button>
    <button id="upd" style="margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 20px; display: none" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>

    <table id="mytable" class="table table-dark" border='1' style="display:none; margin-top:20px ">
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Options</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#snddet').click(function() {
        var name = document.getElementById("PersonName").value;
        var age = document.getElementById("PersonAge").value;
        var country = document.getElementById("PersonCountry").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("PersonCity").value;
        $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          url: "/Person/SendDetails",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            name: name,
            age: age,
            country: country,
            city: city
          },
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
          },
          failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
          }
        });
      });

      $('#upd').click(function() {
        var Id = document.getElementById("PersonId").value;
        var name = document.getElementById("PersonName").value;
        var age = document.getElementById("PersonAge").value;
        var country = document.getElementById("PersonCountry").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("PersonCity").value;

        $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          url: "/Person/editData",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            Id: Id,
            name: name,
            age: age,
            country: country,
            city: city
          },
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
          },
          failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
          }
        });
        $("#upd").hide();
      });


      $('#PersonCountry').change(function() {
        var a = document.getElementById("PersonCountry").value;

        if ($(this).val() == "Pakistan") {
          $("#PersonCity").show();
        } else if ($(this).val() == "Canada") {
          $("#PersonCity").show();
        } else
          $("#PersonCity").hide();

        $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          url: "/Person/getCountry",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            PersonCountry: a
          },
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

          success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            var len = data.length;
            var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a City</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              s += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>';
            }
            $("#PersonCity").html(s);
          },
          failure: function(errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
          }
        });

      });

      $(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "get",
          url: "/Person/getTable",
          dataType: "json",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

          success: function(data) {
            debugger
            var i = 1;
            var j = 1;
            $(data).each(
              function() {
                $('#mytable').append('<tr><td>' + this.Id + '</td><td id="name-' + this.name + '">' + this.name + '</td><td id="age-' + this.age + '">' + this.age + '</td><td>' + this.country + '</td><td>' + this.city + '</td><td> <button class="delbtn" id= "' + this.Id + '"> Delete </button> <button class="editbtn" id= "' + this.Id + '"> Edit </button> </td></tr>')
                if (i == data.length) {
                  $(".delbtn").click(function() {
                    var del = $(this).attr('id');
                    $.ajax({
                      type: "get",
                      url: "/Person/delRow",
                      dataType: "json",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      data: {
                        del: del
                      },
                      success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                        $('#mytable').ajaxStart();


                      },
                      failure: function(errMsg) {
                        alert("failure")
                      }
                    })
                  });
                  $(".editbtn").click(function() {
                    var edit = $(this).attr('id');
                    $('#PersonId').val($(this).parent().siblings()[0].innerText);
                    $('#PersonName').val($(this).parent().siblings()[1].innerText);
                    $('#PersonAge').val($(this).parent().siblings()[2].innerText);
                    $("#upd").show();
                    $("#mytable").toggle();
                  });
                }
                i = i + 1;
              })
          }
        })
      });

      $("#show").click(function() {
        $("#mytable").toggle();
      });

    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can empty table using `$("#mytable").empty();` and refill your table on jquery.ajax call

Comment: can you provide me with a fiddle;''

Comment: Try with this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/r91qkt6y/

Comment: refer this sample https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-add-remove-table-rows-dynamically-using-jquery.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use ajax.It allows web pages to be updated asynchronously.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp